# Getting random item in a table for a game

Tags: lua

```
local limiteds = {
    test1 = {
        value = 999999999,
        itemid = -1,
        released = false
    }
}

function tablelength(T)  
    local count = 0
    for _ in pairs(T) do count = count + 1 end
    return count
end

function randomitem()
    local limited
    repeat
        local limited = limiteds[math.random(tablelength(limiteds))]
    until limited.released == false
end
```

but it is crashing my game at the repeat loop and I cant figure out why. limited seems to be nil for some odd reason?

Comment: You have 2 local's limited

Comment: @kukis still returns nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function randomitem()
  local limited
  repeat
    local key
    for i = 1, math.random(tablelength(limiteds)) do
      key, limited = next(limiteds, key)
    end
  until limited.released == false
  return limited
end
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to EXPLAIN how this fixes his problem? You're basically spoon feeding him, he will never learn from this, and neither will future readers.

Comment: @warspyking: Be glad he posted an actual answer rather than his usual tactic of posting a comment.

Comment: @warspyking - It is not "spoon feeding".  It is [observational learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observational_learning).

Comment: @Egor Haha, I'll use that one next time I need help with my homework. But honestly he probably took his answer and rolled with it. I bet he has no clue what you did.